# Selecting pins in Bing Maps using drag functionality to select multiple pins

Tags: mapping, draggable, bing-maps, multi-select, bing-api

We need a way of selecting multiple pins on a Bing map using mouse click-and-drag functionality.

- The pins represent businesses.
- There may be zero or many pins in any given map area.
- The pins will not be draggable.
- Clicking on a pin will select that pin only.
- However, multiple pins needs to be selected in a quick/simple manner for the user.

Clicking and dragging across multiple pins; there needs to be a way of selecting multiple pins on mass. The existing way of doing this was with something called "Dev Express" which allowed for click-and-drag of a rectangle across multiple pins, which would cause the selection of all corresponding pins.

For us, it's an intended integration of a Bing map into an Oracle CRM product.

The customer uses Bing, and is moving from a proprietary system for which we don't have access to their code.

Image of click-and-drag in existing system:

[image: screenshot map]

The new system hasn't been developed yet - but the developers have queried the 'click and drag' requirement based on the available Bing Mapping API.